# Can't integrate localytics-react-native on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, localytics

I'm trying to integrate the localytics-react-native package to my already existing app and successfully integrated it on android but I can't pass the build phase on iOS.
I followed this [documentation](https://docs.localytics.com/dev/react-native.html#developer-setup) to do so.

After linking it [manually](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios), I followed every step on the localytics documentation.

On the second step `2. Add dependency`, the `libLLLocalytics.a` is already in the **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** section so I skipped this step.
I managed to go trought every step without problem but at the end it doesn't build and I get this error :
[image: error-building-LLLocalytics]

We are managing our natives librairies with cocoapods and and it's the first librairie I have to install without it. Is there a specific configuration I have to do to support the two way of managing them ?

I also tried to follow the [iOS specific](https://docs.localytics.com/dev/ios.html#getting-started-ios) documentation and install the library with pods. It builds but on the JS side when I try to import LLLocalytics, it returns me `undefined`.
[image: import js]
[image: undefined]

Versions :
react-native: 0.57.7
react: 16.6.3
localytics-react-native: 2.3.1

pod --version : 1.4.0

If anybody can help me, I thank you in advance.

Comment: Anyone struggling with this after updating to RN 0.60 should check out this solution: https://forums.expo.io/t/how-do-i-manually-add-pods-headers-public-to-the-header-search-paths-configuration/2427/6. Only that instead of InAppUtils you go to the LLLocalytics target.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, go to [target] -> Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Header Search Paths and add the directory where the dependency is located. The linker just doesn't know where to find the header yet.